# select and calculate schedule dates then put them into an array

Tags: php, mysql, date, scheduled-tasks, schedule

I have a table with posts I want to schedule on Facebook. No schedule dates are stored here.

I have a second table with schedule dates based on week days. All hours are the same but not all weekdays are included. Some of them are missing.

```
| id  | mon   | tue   | wed | thu   | fri | sat   | sun   |
| --- | ----- | ----- | --- | ----- | --- | ----- | ----- |
| 1   | 10:20 | 10:20 |     | 10:20 |     | 10:20 | 10:20 |
| 2   | 15:25 | 15:25 |     | 15:25 |     | 15:25 | 15:25 |
| 3   | 18:25 | 18:25 |     | 18:25 |     | 18:25 | 18:25 |
| 4   | 21:25 | 21:25 |     | 21:25 |     | 21:25 | 21:25 |
| 5   |       |       |     |       |     |       |       |
| 6   |       |       |     |       |     |       |       |
| 7   |       |       |     |       |     |       |       |
```

Let's say we are in the first day of the week (08:00) and I want to calculate the dates for the next 100 posts (5 weeks from now). I'm thinking I ought to get an array with all these dates in UNIX time.

```
$array = array('1439893200','1439896200','1439833200',......'1437893200','1449893200');
```

I need the array because I want to output the dates when I display the posts from the database. The posts can be reordered and the dates can be changed that's why I don't store the schedule dates there. I prefer a separate table for that.

I already spent a lot of time trying to achieve this but without success. Any starting advice and help will be appreciated.

How about we start in Wednesday when there are no scheduled hours?

Comment: Maybe try posting what you have tried and why it fails?